# sql xml response contains &lt: instead of <

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and from that I'm calling a web service that returns XML. To be able to read Swedish characters I do this:

```
select @xml = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@response as nvarchar(max)), 'utf-8', 'utf-16') as xml)
```

Where `@response` is the response I get from the web service. This does make it able to read the Swedish characters but it doesn't change the fact that the XML still looks like shit with the `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`.

How can I change this?

Edit---
This is what i do with the xml response:

```
DECLARE @obj int
DECLARE @Url nvarchar (200)
DECLARE @response varchar(8000)
DECLARE @xml XML

EXEC sp_OACREATE 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @obj OUT
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @Url, false
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send'
    EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responsetext', @response OUT
    select @xml = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@response as nvarchar(max)), 'utf-8','utf-16') as xml)
```

Edit 2----
This is the xml response:
[image]

Comment: What datatype is `@response`. Can you post a sample of the content in `@response`?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson ive made an edit :) it is of type varchar

Comment: Ok, but what is the content. I see there is some XML with utf-8 encoding but to see what happens to &lt; and how to deal with it you have to show the content.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson i put a picture of the response in since stack automatically translates the & lt; to <

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a XML within another XML that only has one root node `string`.

Assign `@response` directly to `@xml` and use `value()` to get the embedded XML as `nvarchar(max)` and then cast to XML.

I did not see how you have ÅÄÖ encoded in there so you might need to adapt the solution to take care of that.

```
declare @xml xml
declare @response varchar(max)

-- Sample response
set @response = '<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org">&lt;?xml version=''1.0'' encoding=''utf-16''?&gt;&lt;PMDataSet&gt;SomeValue&lt;/PMDataSet&gt;</string>'

set @xml = @response
select cast(@xml.value('(*:string/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as xml)
```

Result:

```
<PMDataSet>SomeValue</PMDataSet>
```